# How to add ArrayList in getParams in Volley

Tags: android, android-volley

I need to send an arraylist to my webservices in parameter. The code which i have tried is as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
 Map<String, ArrayList<String>> params = new HashMap<>();
 // the POST parameters:
  params.put(TAG_ITEM, breakfastItemNames);//breakfastItemNames is an arraylist
  params.put(TAG_ITEM_TYPE,breakfastItemType);//breakfastItemType is an arraylist
  params.put(TAG_MENUID, menuIDList);//menuIDList is an arraylist
  return params;
   }
```

However i cant return params as i need to return `Map<String,String>` ,but params is `Map <String,ArrayList<String>>`.

I dont want to send the Arraylist by converting it to string.
Is there any workaround to be able to send Arraylist?

Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : breakfastItemNames){
       sb.append(s);
       sb.append("\t");
    }
    params.put(TAG_ITEM, sb);
    .
    .
    . 
    // likewise for other array list..
    .
    .
    return params;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i don't intend to send string as the webservice api is already made to cater webapp uses. The webapp uses ajax to send all the form data. In that case an array goes through. I am looking for something similiar for android so that the webservices api isnt needed to change